# Error when exporting data from SQL output to csv

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, export-to-csv

I have a SQL that has one of the columns that stores value that begins with a hyphen '-'. When I tried to export it to csv I get an Invalid Name error. When I view it in the SQL editor it shows correctly (Sample : -Coke).

Is there anyway I could have this value saved successfully in the csv file ?

Given below is a sample view of the data

```
Name
-Coke
-Pepsi
```

Sample SQL I used:

```
SELECT name FROM sales WHERE name like '-%';
```

I am using a Redshift DB.

Comment: If you use ms excel import the file with `column data format` as text

Comment: So how exactly did you "export it to CSV"?  Which tool did you use for that?

Comment: Very hard to give any advice unless you explain how you are exporting the data to a CSV file.

Comment: @Nathan, I am trying to export the SQL output to a csv file from the SQL editor

Comment: So, _which_ SQL editor? And _where_ are you seeing the "Invalid Name" error? In the SQL editor? In Excel? You might want to take a look at these tips for writing a question that gives you the best chance of getting a useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Run the query `SELECT name FROM sales WHERE name like '-%';`

Select the all results and right click on it and select *Copy with headers*  then, paste it in Excel. 
Now save excel as a CSV.  Done...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view with your "SELECT name FROM sales WHERE name like '-%';" query, then right click on the database and use Tasks->Export Data in ssms. "Flat file Destination" needs to be selected in "choose destination' if you need the result in csv